# DataTables warning: I used codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

***This message is a popup message with refreshing my page:***

DataTables warning: table id=table - Requested unknown parameter '7' for row 0, column 7. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please check how much th tag and tr tag you take,if you take 4 th and 3 tr or vice verso it give error like you get,
For example

```
  <table>
                  <tbody>
                     <thead>
                         <tr>
                           <th >Id</th>
                           <th >Date</th>
                           <th >name</th>
                           <th >email</th>
                        </tr>
                     </thead>
                      <tr><td>1</td></tr>
                      <tr>21-07-2017</tr>
                      <tr>test</tr>
                </tbody>
   </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please provide more information...
as per the info the seventh column is empty

may be your controller writtens only 6 columns but in your datatable you might have specified seven columns

- check how many columns your controllers written
- check how many columns you have specified in your datatable 
  check in your "aoColumns" array

offical doc : http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/columns